# Are these two pronunciations for "depreciation" correct?

Tags: pronunciation

As I looking for the pronunciations off word 'depreciation', I found that for the letter 'i'(first one), there are two different pronunciation. one is /i/ like 'ee' in bee, and another one is /ɪ/ as 'i' in bit.

Specifically, on www.thefreedictionary.com, the entry for [depreciation](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/depreciation) lists

> 1. (dĭ-prē′shē-ā′shən)
> 2. (dɪˌpriːʃɪˈeɪʃən)

it seems that both of them is right and the /i/sound  is more popular, is that right？

Comment: You need to provide your sources. It might not be a matter of which is correct, but which is used where.

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/depreciation  I found it on this website

Comment: I assume you meant those two. Please [edit] your post if I have cited the wrong ones.

Comment: yes ，that's the two

Comment: @HenryWang Just want to be sure, are you asking about the vowel of "de" or the vowel of "ci(a)" in *depreciation*? (If it's the latter, I'll delete my answer because I misunderstood your question.) -- After reading sumalic's answer, I think sumalic (and @Max) understands your question correctly. I've deleted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct, but it's actually more popular to pronounce the first "i"  in "deprec**i**ation" (the vowel in the third syllable) with the vowel of "bee."

Variation like this between /iː/ and /ɪ/ occurs in specific, predictable contexts: at the end of a word (usually written *-y*) or in an unstressed syllable before another vowel (usually written *-i-*). In these contexts, there is no contrast between these sounds, so they are often grouped together under the name of the "happy vowel."  Traditionally in some British accents (including the prestigious "Received Pronunciation") words like "happy" were pronounced with the /ɪ/ vowel of "kit" or "bit." But Americans, and many British speakers nowadays, pronounce words like "happy" with the /iː/ vowel of "fleece" or "bee."

Geoff Lindsey wrote a blog article about it, "[The fallac[ɪj]of schwee](http://englishspeechservices.com/blog/the-fallac%C9%AAjof-schwee/)," where he recommends using the vowel of "fleece" or "bee" (ē or /iː/) for this sound even if you're trying to use a British accent.

Comment: @sumelic I note that you do not take the OP to task for referring to the Misbegotten Schwee in "one is /i/ like 'ee' in bee..." Does this mean that the battle is lost, that the schwee will ever be with is, or that it has supplanted /iː/?

Comment: @P.E.Dant: Well, "bee" actually has never been considered to have the "schwee" vowel (since it's a stressed syllable) so I assume that rather than using a three-way system of /i:/, /i/ and /ɪ/, the OP was just using a [qualitative transcription](http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/wells/ipa-english.htm), which leaves out vowel length markers. This implies a two-way contrast between /i/ and /ɪ/, with no schwee.

Comment: @sumelic - So we have seen the end of /i:/.

Comment: @P.E.Dant: not exactly. As the article I linked to above says, quantitative-qualitative transcriptions are actually more "standard" for British English. I get the impression purely qualitative transcriptions are more common for American English due to various mergers that have taken place that make vowel length less of a prominent feature.

Comment: @sumelic - So /i:/ has not passed; it has been slurped up. I have noted, particularly in West coast NAmE dialect among suburban white youth, the merger of all unrounded vowels into one: Th/ɜ!/t's t/ɜ!/d/ɜ!/lly /ɜ!/ws/ɜ!/me! I refer to /ɜ!/, this melded all-purpose open-mid central, as the _schwing,_ and predict that by 2045 it will be a dominant vowel in global dialects. **Haro!**